# pick names from a list into a form - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a form where I have created lists of peoples names. I have 2 buttons on my form. One to pick the names and display them onto the form and the other to reset the form.

How do I code it so that the names in the lists are being displayed to the labels I have designated for them.

I want the names be picked at random. For example I have 10 names and I want 4 of those names to be picked at random and displayed. This would help massively. Many thanks.

Visual Studio 2010 C#

Comment: you can behave a list in C# like this : `list[0].name` . maybe if you use `Random` class and receive a number and put that number as index of `list[index]` be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List <string> peopleName = new List <string> ();
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int index = rand.Next(0, 10);
    label1.Text = peopleName[index];
}
```

maybe it wasn't the best but it can help.

Comment: I have added that in and edited about. Works really well thank you. I can do that with the rest of the names needed.

Do you know how I can make it so when I click the "Pick Name" button will choose each name for that position, as currently I have to click the labels for it to choose a random name. Many thanks.

Comment: @T.Fensom: maybe my english is so weak because really i didn't understand what do you want to do as you said in comment. please make your question easier. tnx

Comment: I have the labels displaying the random names as needed which I thank you for, but is there a way I can link up the coding so that the button on the form will choose the names for me.

example; I need 10 random names from 40. How would I get the button to choose these when clicked. thanks

Comment: @T.Fensom: do you mean putting this code in Button Event ?